# Animate a texture / material over a mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, materials, uv

Animate a texture / material over a mesh

The material will animate over a plane correctly but when I try and do something similar with a different mesh it doesn't work as expected (it just flashes blue) how can I fix this.

Note: The reason I'm doing it this way is Verge3d can't animate curves over the web so this would be one way to show the growth / path an object would take over time.

File attached.
I'm using blender 2.81 ubuntu 64bit
[image]

[image: Animated Texture]

[image: material node]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to give an exact answer without knowing exactly which effect you want to achieve, but...

Your object needs a UV map. Here, I've just put a seam down the edge-loop in the crease, and hit 'U' ...

[image]

.. I'm sure you could be more sophisticated about that. Maybe make use of 'Follow Active Quads' if you want the repeat in the texture to reflect the topology of the object more closely.

Optionally..

[image]

You could simplify your shader tree, a Mapping node could replace the separate nodes to animate the UV space, and you could replace the 'Add Shader' node with a 'Mix Shader' node if you want a bit more control over transparency.

[image]

Obviously, you may want different motion, scale, etc.

Comment: Thanks works great!